# Joining two datasets on SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm getting an error on one of the fields for the JCID table, (supposed misspelled ' near JCID). if you separate the datasets and run them by their own both work with no problems, I think it could be some INNE JOINS that I made; I really hope somebody here could help me out. Thank you in advance

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
HQCO.HQCo,
HQCO.Name Name1,
JCJP.Item It1,
JCJP.Phase ph1,
JCCP.CostType,
JCCI.Item It2,
JCCI.Description Desc1,
JCCP.Phase ph2,
JCJP.Description Desc2,
JCCT.Description Desc3,
JCCH.UM,
JCCP.CurrEstUnits,
JCCP.CurrEstCost,
JCCP.ActualUnits,
JCCP.ActualCost,
JCCM.Description Desc4,
JCJP.JCCo,
JCCP.ProjCost,
JCCP.RemainCmtdCost,
JCCP.ProjPlug,
JCCP.Mth mth1,
JCCI.BilledAmt BilledAmt1,
JCCM.BilledAmt BilledAmt2,
JCCI.UnitPrice ,
JCCM.BilledAmt + JCCM.udGEACrev As REVENUE_2,
(JCCM.udGEACrev + JCCM.BilledAmt) - JCCP.ActualCost As BilledCostDifference,
JCCM.udGEACrev,
JCCP.Job,
JCCM.Department,
JCJM.ProjectMgr,
JCMP.Name Name2
   JCID.JCCo, 
   JCID.Contract ,
   vrvJCContractMaster.Description Desc5, 
   JCID.ItemTrans, 
   JCID.ActualDate, 
   JCID.JCTransType, 
   JCID.TransSource, 
   JCID.PostedDate, 
   JCID.BilledUnits, 
   JCID.Description Desc6, 
   JCID.BilledAmt Amt3, 
   JCID.Mth mth2, 
   JCID.BilledTax, 
   vrvJCContractMaster.TaxInterface, 
   HQCO.DefaultCountry

FROM   
    Viewpoint.dbo.JCID AND Viewpoint.dbo.JCCP 
 INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.vrvJCContractMaster  ON JCID.JCCo =    vrvJCContractMaster.JCCo AND JCID.Contract=vrvJCContractMaster.Contract 
INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.HQCO ON JCID.JCCo=HQCO.HQCo
    INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.HQCO ON JCCP.JCCo = HQCO.HQCo
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCT ON JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCT.PhaseGroup AND     JCCP.CostType = JCCT.CostType
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCH ON JCCP.JCCo = JCCH.JCCo AND     JCCP.Job = JCCH.Job  
      AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCH.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase = JCCH.Phase  AND     JCCP.CostType = JCCH.CostType
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJP ON JCCP.JCCo = JCJP.JCCo AND     JCCP.Job = JCJP.Job 
      AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCJP.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase  = JCJP.Phase AND     JCJP.JCCo = 1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCI ON JCJP.JCCo = JCCI.JCCo AND     JCJP.Contract = JCCI.Contract AND JCJP.Item  = JCCI.Item 
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCM ON JCCI.JCCo = JCCM.JCCo AND     JCCI.Contract = JCCM.Contract 
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJM ON JCCM.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND     JCCM.Contract = JCJM.Job 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCMP ON JCJM.JCCo = JCMP.JCCo AND     JCJM.ProjectMgr = JCMP.ProjectMgr













WHERE  
(JCID.JCTransType='AR' OR JCID.JCTransType=’JB' OR JCID.JCTransType='JC' OR     JCID.JCTransType='RA') AND "JCID"."JCCo"=1 
AND(JCID.Mth BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND @EndDate)
   AND JCJM.ProjectMgr = 8
   AND JCCM.Department = '10'


ORDER BY JCID.JCCo, JCID.Contract, JCJP.Contract, JCJP.Item, JCJP.Phase,     JCCP.CostType
```

Comment: No comma between JCMP.Name Name2 and JCID.JCCo?

Comment: I have not seen it before "FROM  Viewpoint.dbo.JCID AND Viewpoint.dbo.JCCP " ?

Comment: Just a thought - `JCID.JCTransType=’JB'` appears to have the wrong type of single quote at the start

Comment: Just realized that, still haven't done the JOINS right and crashes when executing it